# TDGOTCHI in Eclipse - can someone explain how to make it work?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Can anyone explain how I make the TDGOTCHI plugin from http://happyprog.com to work with jUnit tests? I've installed the plugin but can't figure out how to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Window* -> *Show view* -> TDGotchi.

Then start writing tests, execute them or do normal Java refactorings in your test code to get reactions from it.